# Cross-platform C++: wrapping OS-specifics behind a class

Tags: c++, linux, windows, architecture, cross-platform

I'm working on a C++ project which should run on Linux and Windows 7+. This is also my first week with C++ after a very simple and short basics course some years back.

Let's say I need to access the filesystem, but as OS's have different APIs for that I need to create a wrapper class to make things consistent.

Would the following work:

Have a base class `File`. From file I inherit `WinFile` and `LinuxFile`, which implement the base class public methods (e.g. `createFile`, `readFile`, etc.). Then in both sub-classes I implement the public methods to map to platform specific methods (WINAPI file handling and UNIX file handling).

Then I would use a preprocessor directive to conditionally load either `WinFile` or `LinuxFile` in the main application:

```
int main()
{
    #if defined WIN32
    WinFile fileSystem;
    #elif defined LINUX
    LinuxFile fileSystem;
    #endif

    // Both of above contain the same public method API.

    std::string filedata;
    filedata = fileSystem.readFile(...);

    ...
}
```

My gut says that this should work, but are there any drawbacks? Will this become a maintainability problem easily? Are preprocessor directives considered "hacks" or something? I know they're used with header include guards and such, but they're compiler related logic, not application related logic.

Any other ways to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: You may abstract even more by providing something like `std::unique_ptr<FileSystem> MakeFileSystem()` and the preprocessor would only be in your "FileSystem" files.

Comment: And as you cannot change system at runtime, you may have `using FileSystem = LinuxFileSystem;` and then no virtual (but you have to provide identical method).

Comment: I see. That `using = ...` has to be defined in the same file scope where `FileSystem` is to be used in am I correct?

Comment: I would put it directly in `FileSystem.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the API in a header file and move the implementation into cpp files.
Add the .cpp source files dependent on your os (or guard the .cpp files through) macros, for example:

```
// File.h
class File
{
public:
    void open(std::string);
};

// File_impl_win.cpp (compiled when win)
void File::open(std::string)
{
    // impl
}

// File_impl_lin.cpp (compiled when linux)
void File::open(std::string)
{
    // impl
}
```

The advantage is that you don't need to distinguish between a LinuxFile and WindowsFile, you got a single api instead.

But there is an amazing crossplatform boost library for filesystem usage already, [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which you could use.

Comment: I was just wondering whether the header file could be used as an interface for the public methods here. With guarding you mean I just compile a single class with either one or other OS API usage? I'll need to checkout boost. So many have mentioned it in discussions and so on. I heard some boost stuff has been implemented in C++11 and C++14?

Comment: Some libraries from boost were basically taken into the standard (thread, function, chrono...). The filesystem TS http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs for C++17 is based on boost filesystem as well.

Comment: I see. I'll get acquainted some more. Seems useful without creating needless overhead some frameworks give. :)

Comment: Marked your answer accepted, makes me rely on a Makefile solution to determine the compilation of platform files but it does seem like a good solution when considering maintenance and extendability.

Comment: Consider to use CMake instead of makefiles for crossplatform development, it's easier to use and creates makefiles on linux and visual studio solutions on windows.

Comment: I wondered whether Makefiles on their own are enough, heard of CMake but I thought it was just a wrapper around basic Makefiles. Thanks for the pointer. :)